# how can i stop a .net listview itemcheck event?

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a ListView called MyListView that inherits the ListView class. I want to overwrite the whole ItemCheck() / OnItemCheck() . how can i overwrite it completely?

code:

```
Public Class MyListView
    Inherits ListView

    Protected Overrides Sub OnItemCheck(ByVal ice As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs)
        'some code here - for some reason these are the only codes that i want to run
        'stop here - how can i stop it?

        MyBase.OnItemCheck(ice)
    End Sub

End Class
```

i want to stop it there so that the listview in the program will not check/uncheck and only the codes that i put will be exucuted (without continuing running the built in codes)

please help thanks